# Create self contained HTML file with Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

It should be possible to create a self-contained HTML file with Quarto using

```
format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
```

as documented here:
https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html#self-contained, yet when I try to email the resulting HTML file, the chart does not appear, as in this image -[image: []

and I get a file folder along with the HTML file

[image: ![enter image description here][2]][2].]

(I think it was working last week, I'm not sure but I definitely did get a self-contained file).

Am I doing something wrong?

MWE:

````
---
title: "foo"
format: 
  html: 
    embed-resources: true
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point() 
```
````

Using `system("quarto render elevators.qmd --output elevators.html")` gives the same result.

Comment: I am actually getting a self-contained file.  Can you elaborate on "it does not work for me"? How did you find out its not working?

Comment: Thanks for trying. I have added extra detail to explain.

Comment: Oh! you are getting an `elevators_files` folder. Then definitely it is not working! However, what is your quarto version? And I am not able to install `elevators` package.  From where can I install the package?

Comment: Does it work via the command line? E.g. `quarto render test.qmd --output test.html`?

Comment: @shafee updated MWE to replace `elevators` with `mtcars`

Comment: @Julian Nope, I get the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`self-contained: true` works for me, e.g.,

```
format: 
  html:
    self-contained: true
```

using `Quarto v1.2` - the current version at time of writing

Comment: I am quite sure it has something to do with the quarto version. I would recommend specifying your quarto version along with this answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

I solved with this:

```
---
format:
    html: 
       embed-resources: true
---
```

Comment: The question states that I tried this but it didn't work. Could you explain how your answer helps?

Comment: This works wonderfully for me, currently on Quarto 1.3.450 (released end 2023).